# Upload an excel File to Database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to import data from an Excel 2003 file, but my C# program gives error

> External table is not in the expected format

I use this code:

```
string ExcelContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
string Excel2010ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

if (fileuploadExcel.HasFile)
{
    //Check the Content Type of the file 
    if (fileuploadExcel.PostedFile.ContentType == ExcelContentType || fileuploadExcel.PostedFile.ContentType == Excel2010ContentType)
    {
            try
            {
                //Save file path 
                string path = string.Concat(Server.MapPath("~/TempFiles/"), fileuploadExcel.FileName);
                //Save File as Temp then you can delete it if you want 
                fileuploadExcel.SaveAs(path);

                string excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\"";

                // Create Connection to Excel Workbook 
                using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString))
                {
                    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("Select * FROM [Sheet1$]", connection);
                    connection.Open();
                    // Create DbDataReader to Data Worksheet 
                    using (DbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        // SQL Server Connection String 
                        string sqlConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString.ToString();
                        // Bulk Copy to SQL Server 
                        using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnectionString))
                        {
                            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "Excel_table";
                            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dr);
                            lblMessage.Text = "The data has been exported succefuly from Excel to SQL";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lblMessage.Text = ex.Message;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: External table is not in the expected format.

Comment: please provide your complete method where you are doing import functionality. we can find the error.

Comment: give break point next to this line using (DbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader()) and check the value for dr . you don't have any problem in your connection string. you have problem here.

Comment: and add this if(File.Exists(path)) { File.Delete(path) }
else
{
   fileuploadExcel.SaveAs(path);
}

Comment: as in this code only you are using for .xls, please modify this to only for this version . change this -  if (fileuploadExcel.PostedFile.ContentType == ExcelContentType || fileuploadExcel.PostedFile.ContentType == Excel2010ContentType) to if (fileuploadExcel.PostedFile.ContentType == ExcelContentType)

Comment: Hiiiiii  kumarch thanks for ur reply connection.open() it's throws error and change the code as u told but nothing happen error occured

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi here  i am using this to import from Excel File.Try this.Works 100%...
Here you should have a folder inside your application named as "Files" where after uploading your excel file,it  will be stored and your program will read from the excel file available inside "Files" Folder.

```
  protected void btnImport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ArrayList alist = new ArrayList();
        string connString = "";
        string strFileType = Path.GetExtension(fileuploadExcel.FileName).ToLower();
        string fileBasePath = Server.MapPath("~/Files/");
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(this.fileuploadExcel.FileName);
        string fullFilePath = fileBasePath + fileName;

        //Connection String to Excel Workbook
        if (strFileType.Trim() == ".xls")
        {
            connString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + fullFilePath +
                          ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\"";
        }
        else if (strFileType.Trim() == ".xlsx")
        {
            connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fullFilePath +
                         ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\"";
        }
        if (fileuploadExcel.HasFile)
        {
            string query = "SELECT [UserName],[Education],[Location] FROM [Sheet1$]";
           using(OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString))
           {
                if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                conn.Open();
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);

                Session["griddata"] = ds.Tables[0];
                grvExcelData.DataSource = Session["griddata"];
                grvExcelData.DataBind();                  
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I use This Code But same Error Occured

Comment: there would be two issues. if you have downloaded/Exported that excel file and modified something and uploading  - this time your error will occur. so what you need to do is after modification of the downloaded file you need to save it as another excel file name with proper version.

Comment: If I Upload .xlsx File it' uploded Sucessfully But If I have Upoad .xls File Then This Probem occuerd.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Connection String

```
string connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SSIS tool( Sql server integration services)
create connection to excel sheet then add source and destination
your source will be excel sheet and your destination will be Database table
ok?
if you need more info please tell me...